# [WPF]; Expanded event For TreeView in Caliburn.Micro

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

“TreeViewItem.Expanded” event on treeview element, code like this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}"
         [Event TreeViewItem.Expanded]=[Action Expanded($this)];
         [Event TreeViewItem.Collapsed]=[Action Collapsed($dataContext)]">
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
     <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
      ...
     </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
 </TreeView.ItemTemplate></TreeView>
```

it's not working.

Here is My ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel{
.......
public void Expanded(Nodes node)
{
..........
}
}
```

**Thanks**,
Raghava

Comment: Can you elaborate on your requirement??

Answer (score 1):

First off you are missing the largest section of most important code in the first 3 lines...

The code you showed us, is hopefully a typo since it would be a XAML error for sure.
The attached property **Message.Attach** is required for C.M. to see the events you are looking to capture.  Keep in mind then the signatures of those methods need to be exact otherwise CM won't find them in your viewmodel.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}"
         Message.Attach="[Event TreeViewItem.Expanded]=[Action Expanded($this)];
         [Event TreeViewItem.Collapsed]=[Action Collapsed($dataContext)]">
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
     <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
      ...
     </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
 </TreeView.ItemTemplate></TreeView>
```

My suggestion is to create those methods on the view's codebehind first with a double click on that event in the properties window.  Then replicate the method in your viewmodel, you can leave out certain things but for it to work it must be wired up as I have indicated.

Morgan.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to get the IsExpanded item in the view model, then you can bind the TreeViewItem's IsExpanded to a property in the viewmodel.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
     <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
     <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Style>
```

ViewModel code:

```
public class ViewModel
{

    private bool isExpanded;
    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get
        {
            return isExpanded;
        }
        set
        {
            isExpanded = value;
            MessageBox.Show("IsExpanded changed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am asking **event** For Dynamically adding data in caliburn.micro